# Is it a good practice to use Chinese/Japanese characters (漢字 / かな) for HTML5 elements' id property? How to validate?

Tags: javascript, html, cjk

The project I'm working on has several element whose id has been set to

Chinese/Japanese characters. For example:

```
<textarea id="メモ欄"></textarea>
```

So far It works fine in our project.

---

If it is permitted how should I write the `validateId()` method for valid id

contains Chinere/Japanese characters?

Thanks in advance!

---

/* ------------------ Feedback ------------------ */

I work in Japan, my team language is Japanese.

Thanks for the answers by now. I decide to use Chinere/Japanese characters.

The function I'm working on allow user to set the id property.

So I need to make sure the user input is a valid id.

Now the question for me is  **How to validate the id input (with regular expression) in javascript?**

Comment: I think it's possible. HTML5 allows any character except any type of space character. And, it must not be an empty string.

Comment: But if you want to be HTML4/XHTML compatible, then note that only ascii and digits (if not at start) were allowed.

Comment: *Is it good practice?* - This depends on your location. It would be a good practice to use an identifier that is the most readable. If you are in Japan, using Japanese might be a good idea if the developers do not know that "memoColumn" means "メモ欄". If you are in Europe, probably not so much.

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3c HTML5.2 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#elements-attributes) you can use any Chinese/Japanese characters as long as they are **Unicode characters**.

[Here](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-unified-ideographs/) you can see what Chinese/Japanese chars are supported .

So I guess you are free yo use those chars. I dont understand your validateId() question.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it works with CN/JP characters. See e.g.

```js
document.getElementById("汉字").style.color = "#ddd"
```

```css
#汉字 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>

<div id="汉字">123</div>
```

However, according to w3c (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp), and my developing experience, it is a bad pratice to do so.

- Difficult to locate.
- Code may be messy when charset changes such as utf to gbk, etc.
- Hard to maintain. Consider the circumstance that there comes a new English speaking developer, and your classes are all in Japanese. Oops.

/* ------------------ edited ------------------ */

What ClockBolt said is totally right. After searching official HTML guides,

> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#classes
>   There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
>   The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.

Comment: W3Schools is not W3C. Their documentation is not official and should not be cited as such.